# Add a string at the end of my ajax url beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I don't know why I can't get this to work. I have a code to GET objects via Ajax:

Here is my code:

```
var $form = $(document).find('#my_form');
const $objectassemblepoint = $('#my_object_assemble_point');

     function convertFromDataToArray(formData) {
            let data = [];
            formData.forEach(function (obj) {
                if (obj.value) {
                    // break with price
                    if (['min_price', 'max_price'].includes(obj.name)) {
                        const dataValue = $form.find('input[name=' + obj.name +']').data(obj.name.substring(0, 3));
                        if (dataValue == parseInt(obj.value)) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    data.push(obj);
                }
            });
            return data;
        }

     if ($form.length) {
            $(document).on('submit', '#my_form', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const $form = $(event.currentTarget);
                const formData = $form.serializeArray();
                let data = convertFromDataToArray(formData);
                let uriData = [];

                const $elPage = $objectassemblepoint.find('input[name=page]');
                if ($elPage.val()) {
                    data.push({name: 'page', value: $elPage.val()});
                }

                data.map(function (obj) {
                    uriData.push(encodeURIComponent(obj.name) + '=' + obj.value);
                });

                var popStateUrl = $form.attr('action') + (uriData && uriData.length ? ('?' + uriData.join('&')) : '');

                var addThisToEnd = '&q=luxury';

                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'), // Plainly: "https://mydomainname.com/joggers" from my actual form
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        //Do stuffs before send
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.error === false) {
                            $objectstoadd.html(response.data);
                            
                            if (popStateUrl !== window.location.href) {
                                window.history.pushState(data, response.message, popStateUrl);
                            }
                        } else {
                            showError(response.message || 'Something went wrong!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        handleError(response);
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        //Some things to do
                    }
                });
         }
```

With the above code, when the user selects a type of joggeres, the url from Ajax becomes:

```
https://mydomainname.com/joggers?min_price=0&max_price=100&thetype%5B%5D=1&_=[TIMESTAMP]
```

But I desire something like this rather:

```
https://mydomainname.com/joggers?min_price=0&max_price=100&thetype%5B%5D=1&q=luxury&_=[TIMESTAMP]
```

I have tried doing:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action')+addThisToEnd // Since I have a variable with the string as above,
```

But everything gets messy. Please I do not know much of Ajax. Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't ie be `var addThisToEnd = '&q=luxury';`

Comment: Can you adding q into data object i.e., data.p = 'luxury' before making the ajax call.

Comment: @Marco sorry I should edit that in my question. But that's what I'm actually doing but it's not working. I mean it's not adding to the end before sending.

Comment: @AdityaAkella I have tried that but not also working. the url I get from doing that is: **https://mydomainname.com/joggers&q=luxury** which is not my expected outcome

Comment: Add this line before ajax call `data = data + "&q=luxury";`

Comment: @YounesBennour I have done that and I get this: **https://mydomainname.com?[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object]&q=luxury** any ideas?

Comment: replace it by `data.q = 'luxury'` it will working

Comment: In your attempt: `url: $form.attr('action') + addThisToEnd`  did you change it to `?q=` not '&q='?   The comment above with `data.q = 'luxury'` is the correct way to do this, not by appending anything manually to the url string.

Comment: Don't append a string to your data *object* - you'll just get `"[object Object]"`

Comment: @YounesBennour could you explain further how to add `data.q = 'luxury'` I have added in beforeSend no error and not working, then I have also added it before `$.ajax({` yet nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @Urget Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provided your full script to understand your problem, but this It will show you if you forgot something in your script:

Edit: Function convertFromDataToArray you don't need it cause data is already is array

```js
    var $form = $(document).find('#my_form');
    const $objectassemblepoint = $('#my_object_assemble_point');

    if ($form.length) {
        $(document).on('submit', '#my_form', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const $form = $(event.currentTarget);
            const data = $form.serializeArray();
            let uriData = [];

            const $elPage = $objectassemblepoint.find('input[name=page]');
            if ($elPage.val()) {
                data.push({ name: 'page', value: $elPage.val() });
            }

            data.map(function (obj) {
                uriData.push(encodeURIComponent(obj.name) + '=' + obj.value);
            });

            var popStateUrl = $form.attr('action') + (uriData && uriData.length ? ('?' + uriData.join('&')) : '');


            var addThisToEnd = {name: 'q', value:'luxury'};
            data.push(addThisToEnd);

            console.log($form.attr('action') + '?' + $.param(data));


            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'), // Plainly: "https://mydomainname.com/joggers" from my actual form
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //Do stuffs before send
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.error === false) {
                        $objectstoadd.html(response.data);

                        if (popStateUrl !== window.location.href) {
                            window.history.pushState(data, response.message, popStateUrl);
                        }
                    } else {
                        showError(response.message || 'Something went wrong!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    //handleError(response);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    //Some things to do
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form" action="https://yourdomain.com/joggers">
        Min price: <input type="text" name="min_price" value="20"><br>
        Max price: <input type="text" name="max_price" value="100"><br>
        The Type: <input type="text" name="thetype" value="test"><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This looks so awesome, I have updated my question with more codes, probably you will be able to help me figure it out. Notice in place of `var data = $form.serialize() + "&q=luxury";` in my code it is `const formData = $form.serializeArray();` Thanks a million.

Comment: When I go exactly by your code I get this error: `e.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Check my answer, I have updated it

Comment: But just one quick question. What if I have to actually place it as the first parameter?   When I do that going by your comments and explanations I get something like: `https://mydomainname.com/joggers?q=luxury?min_price=0&max_price=100&thetype%5B%5D=1&_=[TIMESTAMP]` please notice the double `?` which makes the url wrong. You've clearly answered my question. I only wanted to know if you could show me to tweak it to do from the start, so I might add more knowledge for another time. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you need to put it as first element just replace `data.push(addThisToEnd);` to `data.unshift(addThisToEnd);`, you're welcome :)

Comment: Perfect!!! I am so deeply grateful. Thank you so much. I am humbled.

Comment: You're welcome bro  :)